# Get a new random number every day in JS or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, math, logic

I am building a Joke of the day mini-app And can not quiet figure out how to generate a new random number every day. The random number points to a joke in the json. I have the random number part working, but I only need it to randomize on a new day,and not every browser refresh.

Here is what I got so far

```
<script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $.getJSON('js/jokes.json', function (data) {
                    var randomJoke = (Math.floor(Math.random() * data.OneLiners.length));
                    var newJoke = randomJoke;
                    var decide = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 2));
                    var jokeofDay = data.OneLiners[newJoke].joke;
                    var riddleofDay = data.Riddles[newJoke].Question;
                    var riddleAnswer = data.Riddles[newJoke].Answer;
                    var riddle = "Question: " + riddleofDay + "<br/> Answer: " + riddleAnswer;
                    if (decide == 0) {
                        document.getElementById("JoD").innerHTML = jokeofDay + " ";
                    } else {
                        document.getElementById("JoD").innerHTML = riddle;
                    }
                });
            });

                if(jQuery) console.log('jQuery is loaded.');
        </script>
```

Comment: Do you need the random number to be generated once a day and persisted, or can it be a different random number on every page load?

Comment: the number needs to persist all day, and just generate a new one on a new day

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is to store the value in a cookie with an expiry time. That way you can leave it up to the browser to decide whether the joke ID has expired or not. This is a pure JS example of how you could do it:

```
// Will return a joke id between the min and max values. Once the joke ID has 
// been generated for the day, it is persisted in a cookie until midnight.
function getJokeId(minId, maxId) {
  var jokeId = getCookie('joke');

  if (jokeId !== null) {
    return jokeId;
  }

  var expire = new Date();
  expire.setHours(23,59,59,0);

  jokeId = Math.floor(Math.random()*(maxId - minId + 1) + minId);

  document.cookie = 'joke='+jokeId+';expires='+expire.toGMTString()+';path=/';

  return jokeId;
}


// Just a helper function for accessing cookies in JS - could be replaced with 
// jQuery plugin or similar if needed.
function getCookie(name) {
  var value = "; " + document.cookie;
  var parts = value.split("; " + name + "=");

  if (parts.length == 2) {
    console.log('Found joke ID from cookie');
    return parts.pop().split(";").shift();
  }

  console.log('No joke ID found - new one needed');
  return null;
}

getJokeId(0, 5);
```

Here's a JS Fiddle of the example code: https://jsfiddle.net/edcs/0Lpg9ro6/

Answer (score 0):

If it's OK for each user to get their own random value, but for it to only change once a day, use a cookie or `.localStorage` to remember how long it is since they last got a new value.

Otherwise, you'd have to implement your own random number generator.  The one built-into JS doesn't allow you to specify your own "seed".

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random):

> The implementation selects the initial seed to the random number generation algorithm; it cannot be chosen or reset by the user.

Comment: Well it doesn't matter if different users get different jokes,as long as that joke persists all day. It is only going to be displayed on a few computers anyway(for now). It is part of a project at work. My team is developing a app that displays stuff like weather, time, stock prices,and other tid bits, and I wanted to put the Joke of the day on there as a nod to the guy in support that writes it on the white board every day. It will be put on a rasberry pi eventually, and displayed on a large monitor in the break room.